# While using alias in joins (in Oracle) I'm getting no response in hackerrrank platform

Tags: sql, oracle, join, alias

```
-- This query is not working 
SELECT 
    S.NAME, G.GRADE, S.MARKS 
FROM 
    STUDENTS AS S 
LEFT JOIN 
    GRADES AS G ON S.MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK; 

-- However, this query IS working - why?    
SELECT 
    STUDENTS.NAME, GRADES.GRADE, STUDENTS.MARKS 
FROM 
    STUDENTS 
LEFT JOIN 
    GRADES ON STUDENTS.MARKS BETWEEN GRADES.MIN_MARK AND GRADES.MAX_MARK;
```

I expected the same output as query 2

Comment: Can you provide sample schema and data? Do you get errors or any indication that it's not working? Are these your full queries?

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "not working".  If it gives an error, show it.  If it gives unexpected results, show them, and explain what you expected instead.

Comment: I've used table aliases only for subquery factoring clauses and for select list items. Try it without "as".

Comment: In Oracle the `AS` keyword is forbidden before a table alias. You want `SELECT S.NAME, G.GRADE, S.MARKS FROM STUDENTS S LEFT JOIN GRADES G ON S.MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK;`